# Can't parse JSON from URL no data infinite loading

Tags: json, wordpress, parsing

I'm studying how to get JSON data from URL. I've red a lot and understood that WordPress has implemented the no longer used "REST API V2" plugin, so now every WordPress Site has its json compatible address by default. Yesterday I have found [this tutorial](https://demonuts.com/json-parsing-android-url/) and I decided to apply it to my project, because I think it is the best way to parse and get JSON data from internet.

So I have customized it and I have no errors in coding, but it doesn't fetch data from the URL. The app tells me I have "no data" and then starts an infinite loading.

In the Logcat while it's loading I have this:

```
2019-02-24 13:41:15.589 571-701/? E/SDM: scalar::adjustSourceCrop: Source crop exceeds source image size: Crop(x,y,w,h)=(0,0,720,1440) Src(x,w)=(0,0)
2019-02-24 13:41:15.589 571-701/? E/SDM: ScalarConfig::ApplyScale: Scalar library failed to configure scale data!
```

This is the [JSON url](https://thewam.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts) (you can use [this viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)).

This is my project -> [GitHub](https://github.com/ffantucchio/JSON.git)

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qO9d9BBR5Uw2xS5Ec8wJLrcWYymNa2U2/view?usp=sharing) is what I get when I run the app.

Is it something linked with the wrong JSON url? Maybe I din't get how the whole process works.

Answer (score 0):

In you `ParseContent` class you assume that `JSON` payload is an `JSONObject` but it is a `JSONArray`. In [`JSON` viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) you can verify it. `JSON` looks like below:

```
[{...},{...},{...},...,{...}]
```

So, you need to get another approach to read data. See below example how this `JSON` should be parsed using [`org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        String json = Files.readAllLines(jsonFile.toPath()).stream().collect(Collectors.joining());

        List<TemplateModel> infos = getInfo(json);
        infos.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<TemplateModel> getInfo(String response) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
        List<TemplateModel> models = new ArrayList<>(array.length());
        for (Object item : array.toList()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map) item;
            TemplateModel model = new TemplateModel();
            model.setCategories(((List) map.get("categories")).get(0).toString());
            model.setTitle(((Map) map.get("title")).get("rendered").toString());
            model.setAuthor(map.get("author").toString());
            model.setDate(map.get("date").toString());

            models.add(model);
        }

        return models;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
TemplateModel{categories='365', title='Dai sofisti a Rousseau: quanto è democratico il televoto?', author='21', date='2019-02-24T12:02:22'}
TemplateModel{categories='235', title='Piedi screpolati e cattivo odore: tranquille, c&#8217;è la salvia', author='26', date='2019-02-24T11:14:49'}
TemplateModel{categories='495', title='Camarillo Brillo: 10 dischi più venduti della settimana 16-23 feb', author='27', date='2019-02-24T10:13:24'}
TemplateModel{categories='527', title='La Paranza dei Bambini, il pm: &#8220;La realtà è molto peggio&#8221;', author='1', date='2019-02-23T19:26:05'}
TemplateModel{categories='527', title='Festa: farò la rivoluzione ad Avellino. L&#8217;apertura a Petitto', author='11', date='2019-02-23T19:06:40'}
TemplateModel{categories='525', title='Cocaina Avellino, blitz nel parcheggio e in casa: in due nei guai', author='1', date='2019-02-23T17:42:03'}
TemplateModel{categories='525', title='Irpinia maltempo: vento abbatte alberi e pali|VIDEO e FOTO', author='23', date='2019-02-23T16:57:11'}
TemplateModel{categories='524', title='Valle del Sabato in rivolta contro fonderia: basta veleni!|VIDEO', author='38', date='2019-02-23T12:23:56'}
TemplateModel{categories='460', title='I segreti per scrivere un post di successo su Facebook', author='34', date='2019-02-23T12:19:52'}
TemplateModel{categories='525', title='Avellino, crolla albero a 2 passi dal teatro. Punto sul maltempo', author='23', date='2019-02-23T10:38:28'}
```

Your `ParseContent.isSuccess` and `ParseContent.getErrorCode` methods do not make sense, because `JSON` payload does not contain these information. If you received `JSON` payload it means it is already `OK`.

**EDIT after comment**
If you can not use `toList` method try below approach to read `JSON`:

```
private static List<TemplateModel> getInfo(String response) {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
    List<TemplateModel> models = new ArrayList<>(array.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
        TemplateModel model = new TemplateModel();
        model.setCategories(((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("categories")).get(0).toString());
        model.setTitle(((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("title")).get("rendered").toString());
        model.setAuthor(jsonObject.get("author").toString());
        model.setDate(jsonObject.get("date").toString());

        models.add(model);
    }

    return models;
}
```

Comment: I had to change something due sdk version, but I still can't try your code beacuse I have an error with array.toList (cannot resolve method). This [link](https://i.postimg.cc/dVRjPFzz/Cattura.jpg) is what i get and these [link](https://i.postimg.cc/3wSLV7G3/cattura2.png) are the methods android studio suggests.

Comment: @Francesco, which version of [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) do you use? Can you upgrade it to the newest one?

Comment: Ok, I think I've upgraded to the latest one. I have uploaded the current MainActivity and ParseContent on GitHub (MainActivityEDIT and ParseContentEDIT) [link](https://github.com/ffantucchio/JSON) , because now I havn't errors in coding and any toast with "No Data", but it still loads without showing anything.

Comment: @Francesco, you can not copy-and-paste example from `SO` and expect that it will be working just like that in your app. I showed you have to properly parse `JSON` payload and you need to make similar changes in your code.

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to do it. I will edit the post with the right code as soon as I'll succeed.